# AttributeError: 'Box' object has no attribute 'shape' in Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I tired to load a model using stable-baselines3 in colab use the following code:

```
!pip install stable-baselines3[extra]
from stable_baselines3 import DQN
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv

MODEL_PATH = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Reinforcement_Learning/SpaceInvaders/model_9"
env = gym.make("SpaceInvaders-v0")
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])
```

I received a warning after create the envirnoment:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gym/logger.py:30: UserWarning: WARN: obs_type "image" should be replaced with the image type, one of: rgb, grayscale
  print("%s: %s" % ("INFO", msg % args), file=sys.stderr)
```

Then I tried to load my pre-trained model

```
model = DQN.load(MODEL_PATH,env=env)
```

But received the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-edceae40609f> in <module>()
----> 1   model = DQN.load(MODEL_PATH,env=env)


2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gym/spaces/box.py in __eq__(self, other)
    138         return sample.astype(self.dtype)
    139 
--> 140     def contains(self, x):
    141         if not isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
    142             logger.warn("Casting input x to numpy array.")

AttributeError: 'Box' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I tried the same code in my local Linux, and it works fine.

I would greatly appreciate any help or advice.